# Get Eclipse variable with the name of a file that is not in the project

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to find a way to navigate to the folder containing the current opened file from Eclipse. I have read [this tutorial](http://shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/locate-source-file-on-local-disc-in-eclipse-external-tool/) which describes an External Tool that I have adapted as follows:

- Location: `/usr/bin/nemo` (or file mananger of your choice)
- Arguments: `${resource_path}`

This works fine, as long as the editor contains a file that is in a project. However, if I have F3'd through an include and I am now in a system include file (for example), or I have opened some other non-project file, this method fails with the error `Variable references empty selection: ${resource_path}`.

I know Eclipse knows the filename, because it a) opened the file in the first place and 2) it's in the title bar. How can I get this into an External Tool?

Alternatively, is it possible to get Eclipse to use the current file's location as the default directory in the open dialog? It's annoying to have to navigate though a lot of hierarchy every time you open a resource in a new location.